# Link to full-size image for subscriber only

Tags: images, links, subscription

I'm looking for a way to disable the "link to full-size image" for people that are not logged in. I would like that people become a subscriber before they can download my full size images.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is... its a 3 step process..

1. Check if user is logged in
2. return check and create an if condition
3. return the BIG image link or not at all (right?)

**The code (not check for user level since subscriber is the lowest level)**

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo '<a href=""><img src="LINK TO BIG PICTURE"></a>';
} else {
    echo 'Only Subscribers can view the link to the full image. Register Today!';
}
```

.
Hope this helps.
Cheers, Sagive.